# Can't invoke EJB/CDI bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, jsf-2.2, shiro, omnifaces

I don't know my application with websocket (Tyrus 1.1) can't invoke any CDI or EJB bean. I'm running on Glassfish 4.1 with Server-Sent Event, Websocket 1.1, etc

When I called to JSF managed bean (CDI) from my websocket app, it showed "Error: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped".

If I called to EJB stateless bean from my websocket app, it showed messages as follows:

```
Warning:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB ChatSessionBean, method: public com.mnik.chat.entity.ChatInfo com.mnik.chat.ejb.ChatSessionBean.findRoomId(java.lang.String)
Warning:   javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:750)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.checkExceptionNoTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:640)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:482)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy427.findRoomId(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:414)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at com.mnik.chat.ejb.LocalChatSessionBean$59891376$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.findRoomId(Unknown Source)
    at com.mnik.chat.server.ChatServer.startChatChannel(ChatServer.java:103) ...

Caused by: org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.
    at org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager(SecurityUtils.java:123)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject$Builder.<init>(Subject.java:627)
    at org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSubject(SecurityUtils.java:56)
    at com.mnik.intercept.ShiroSecurityInterceptor.interceptShiroSecurity(ShiroSecurityInterceptor.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor109.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 49 more
```

If you have any suggestion, please share us. Thank you.

Noted: these are my ChatServer (websocket) class:

...

```
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;   
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig;
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat-server/{roomNumbers}",
    subprotocols = {"chat"},
    decoders = {ChatDecoder.class},
    encoders = {ChatEncoder.class},
    configurator = ChatServerHttpSSConfig.class)

public class ChatServer {

public ChatServer() {
    this.dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

}

private final static String USERNAME_KEY = "USERNAME";
private final static String USERNAMES = "USERNAMES";
private final static String INCREASED = "INCREASED";
private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
private final static String ASSOCIATED_HTTPSESSION = "WEBSOCKET_HTTP_SESSION";
private final static String ROOMNUMBERS = "ROOMNUMBERS";
private final static String USERTYPE = "USERTYPE";
private final static String AGENT = "AGENT";
private final static String CLIENT = "CLIENT";
private HttpSession httpSession;
private Session session;

@Inject
private LocalChatSessionBean localChatSS;

@Inject
private SSEAnnounce sseAnnounce;
@Inject
private ProductMsgStates productMsgStates;

@OnOpen
public void startChatChannel(@PathParam("roomNumbers") final String roomNumbers, final Session session, EndpointConfig epc) {
    //for forward-backward html page. 
    ServerEndpointConfig endpointConfig = (ServerEndpointConfig) epc;
    ChatServerHttpSSConfig cshSSC = (ChatServerHttpSSConfig) endpointConfig.getConfigurator();

    //to associate with httpSession
    this.httpSession = (HttpSession) epc.getUserProperties().get(ChatServerHttpSSConfig.CHAT_HTTP_SESSION);
    this.session = session;
    this.session.getUserProperties().put(ASSOCIATED_HTTPSESSION, this.httpSession);

    //normal operation
    this.session.getUserProperties().put(ROOMNUMBERS, roomNumbers);
    System.out.println("Roomnumber at " + this.getClass() + ", ID: " + roomNumbers);

    //when calling to EJB or JSF managed bean, it showed error. In this example code, it calls EJB.
    ChatInfo chatInfo = localChatSS.findRoomId(roomNumbers);
    String productname = chatInfo.getProductname();

    SessionInfo ssInfo = new SessionInfo();
    ssInfo.setSessionId(this.session.getId());
    ssInfo.setChatInfo(chatInfo);
    chatInfo.getSessionsIds().add(ssInfo);
```

...

Comment: Can you give the last part of the exception strace with Caused By:

Comment: Yes, I've addedd on posted info.

Comment: You're using technology that you've neglected to mention here, which may be relevant to answering your question

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I also used Shiro for this app. Now I found out the reason I could not call JSF/EJB bean. And the solution is http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/UnavailableSecurityManagerException-in-MDB-td7578445.html#a7578463